# How can I use the GeoLocation PlugIn in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm having difficulties with getting GeoLocation working in Ionic 3. I've
looked at several tutorials and run into the same problem with all of them.
Here is my setup.

```
PS C:\> ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\myID\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.10.0
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

PS C:\>
PS C:\>
PS C:\>
PS C:\> ionic cordova plugin list
> cordova plugin ls
v Running command - done!
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
PS C:\>
PS C:\>
PS C:\>
```

In setting up a hello-world / blank geo location app, I get errors referencing the
GeoLocation plugin.

```
// app.module.ts
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
// ...
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Geolocation  // <-- Errors here
  ]
```

I can get around this error by adding the ngx suffix:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
// ...
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Geolocation  // OK now
  ]
```

However, when I actually go to use it:

```
//home.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  lat: any;
  lng: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public geo: Geolocation) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
      this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
      this.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

}
```

I start getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at Geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

Commenting out the call to `getCurrentPosition` makes the error go away.

What have I missed? Have I got the wrong version of the plugin? Is there a way
to know which one works with the last version of Ionic 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the Geolocation plugin v3? As you can see [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/geolocation/), the command is:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation@4
```

After installing it, you have to import the plugin into **app.module** as well into your **home.ts**

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

The code to use the plugin is right, so you don't need to change it.

```
this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
   this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
   this.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```